# How can I create a custom popup message when I open an app?

Tags: notifications

I want to be able to have a popup message when I open an app, say Facebook, that reminds me that I'm wasting time..

That is:

1. Click on Facebook app.
2. Facebook opens.
3. A message pops up saying "You should be working" (or any custom message I would like).
4. I can accept and continue on Facebook.

I'm thinking there could be an app for this but I can't find what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an automation app to accomplish it. Here is how to do it with [MacroDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid):

1. In the Triggers tab, in the Applications section, select "Application Launched/Closed, choose Application Launched and enable `Force legacy mechanism`, click OK. Select an app on the list, then click OK.
2. In the Actions tab, in the Notifications section, select "Display Dialog". Enter a title and the message to display.
3. Give the macro a name and save it. It will look like the image below.

Whenever you launched the selected app, a message with the title and message you set will be displayed.

[image]